# Пауза во время работы программы.

Tags: c++

Есть такой участок кода.

```
void Control()
{
    _getch();
    switch(button)
    {
    case 8: pause++;
    }
}

void Start()
{
    Control();
    while(pause == false)
    {
        Iteration();
        Render();
    }
}
```

Необходимо поставить программу "на паузу" при нажатии клавиши пробел. Дело в том, что если поставить Control() в цикле с итератором и рендером, то для каждого кадра придётся нажать пробел. Что делать дальше? =/

Comment: Всё, спасибо, использовал функцию _kbhit()

Comment: Вы слишком усложнили код - прислушайтесь к первому ответу.

Comment: Рассказали бы вы о своей задаче. Возможно и без пауз это можно реализовать...

Comment: пишу игру жизнь в консоли с возможностью редактирования. Вот весь файл проекта. http://yadisk.cc/d/Nngpp3ub1pV
Пишу в консоли потому-что хочу сначала прописать алгоритмы, а потом перевести в окно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы `_getch()` замените на `kbhit()` - жизнь сразу покажется проще. Разница между ними в том, что `getch()` и его разновидности блокируют выполнение потока, пока не будет произведен ввод. `kbhit()` просто опрашивает нажата ли кнопка и сразу возвращает управление. Соответственно, и отличается загрузка процессора при вызове этих функций.

Comment: Спасибо, уже понял сам =)

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, зачем вам switch? Неужели обычным if'ом не обойтись?
Во-вторых, я так понимаю pause - это у вас глобальная переменная? Если да, то тоже не очень хороший тон. Пусть она у вас будет объявлена в Control(), а Control() пусть возвращает unsigned char (в случае, если в функции могут возникнуть ошибки, то short, а char потом 0хFF отделять).
Ну и как задачу решил бы я с учетом всего написанного выше: делаете глобальный бесконечный цикл, а внутри ставите вызов контрола и используете результат его выполнения. Паузу я бы ставил обычным sleep'ом.

Comment: Это всё в классе, а switch на будущее.P.S И я уже сделал. Ну посмотрю что можно сделать =)

Answer (score 0):

Вынести вызовы `Iteration(); Render();` в отдельный поток, запускать и останавливать выполнение потока по нажатию пробела.

Comment: Не соглашусь. Мы не знаем под какую ОС пишет ТС. Мало ли под DOS, а там про потоки вообще ни слова :-)

Comment: Судя по ссылке он пишет минимум под Windows 95
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: А разве _kbhit() не однозначно определяет систему?